# Problems restoring a Snapshot via VirtualBox Java API

Tags: java, virtualbox, restore, snapshot, locked

I want to restore snapshots of a VirtualBox VM and start the VM with the snapshot immediately afterwards.
I write in Java using the VirtualBox API and I use the VBoxWebSrv.exe in Windows.

Most times the restoring and starting works, but sometimes I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.virtualbox_5_1.VBoxException: VirtualBox error: rc=0x80bb0007 The machine 'win7test' is already locked by a session (or being locked or unlocked) (0x80bb0007)
```

The exception occurs, when the following line is executed:
    vm.launchVMProcess(session, "gui", "");

I'm calling ***session.unlockMachine()*** when the application finishes, so the machine shouldn't be locked anymore.

This is my code (I marked the mentioned line):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Number of Snapshot to restore
    int snapNo = 3;
    snapshotUUID = UUIDs[snapNo];


    System.out.println("CONNECT...");

    // Connect to VboxWebSrv
    VirtualBoxManager mgr = VirtualBoxManager.createInstance(null);
    mgr.connect("http://localhost:18083", "MY_WINDOWS_USERNAME", "MY_WINDOWS_PASSWORD");

    // Get VM by name
    IMachine vm = mgr.getVBox().findMachine("win7test");
    // get Session
    ISession session = mgr.getSessionObject();

    // Lock VM to Session
    vm.lockMachine(session, LockType.Shared);

    IProgress progress;



    // ------------ STOP VM ------------

    // get Console to manage the VM
    IConsole console = session.getConsole();

    if (console != null) {
        // STOP VM
        progress = console.powerDown();
        progress.waitForCompletion(25000);
    }



    // ------------ RESTORE SNAPSHOT ------------

    // get Snapshot by UUID
    ISnapshot snapshot = vm.findSnapshot(snapshotUUID);

    progress = session.getMachine().restoreSnapshot(snapshot);
    progress.waitForCompletion(25000);

    try {
        System.out.println("unlock machine...");
        // Put this in a try-catch-block because sometimes this caused an exception too during some tests
        session.unlockMachine();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    // ------------ START VM ------------

    progress = vm.launchVMProcess(session, "gui", ""); // <<<<< HERE THE EXCEPTION OCCURS!
    progress.waitForCompletion(25000);

    // Unlock VM
    session.unlockMachine();

    System.out.println("DONE...");

}
```

Comment: It looks like it's still in the process of unlocking the session when trying to launch the VM. Putting a sleep in before starting the vm worked for me, but there may be a better way to check that the session is unlocked

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I managed to make it more stable but still have a lot of problems. Unfortunately the errors I get aren't always the same.

I created a thread in the official VirtualBox forums but unfortunately there is no solution yet. :(

Here is the link to the thread:
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=83598